# Word request - a unison part

Tags: terminology, intervals

What do you call a part or a moment in music when several players play it in unison. For instance in rock music when a bass player, guitar player, keyboard player and drummer play a part in unison just before a chorus, bridge or a verse. Or maybe they play some rhythm in unison or a phrase of any kind. Or in symphonic music when the whole orchestra plays a part in unison?

Comment: It's just called Unison, no fancy musical terms.

Comment: So you just say, "This part is played in unison"?

Comment: Yes. Why would it be called anything else? Unison alone pretty much covers it.

Comment: I was wondering whether it had a term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just called Unison, no fancy musical terms.

1.. *coincidence in pitch of two or more musical tones, voices etc.* - [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unison)

2.. *A combination of notes, voices, or instruments at the same pitch or (especially when singing) in octaves.* - [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unison)

1a.. *identity in musical pitch; specifically: the interval of a perfect prime* - [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unison)

2.. *coincidence in pitch of sounds or notes.* - [Google Definitions](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20unison)

Comment: That counts only for the perfect unison, the augmented unison is none of those things.

Comment: But no-one mentioned aug. unison, and that's an interval. Nothing at all  to do with the OP's question on different instruments playing together - when they would all be playing the same notes.

Comment: So, does this mean that drums cannot play 'in unison' with others? (No pitch).

Comment: These definitions should include rhythm as well as pitch. If two instruments play the same pitch using different rhythms, it's not unison.

Comment: @endorph I agree! I notice that many dictionaries, even the famous ones, have a distorted definition. Feel free to edit my answer and add in a reliable 'muso' definition!

Comment: Oddly enough, my 'bible', Oxford Companion to Music, doesn't reference unison...